# gridview data is null in when passing gridview to another method

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I bind the gridview in the following event:(subjectdropdown_SelectedIndexChanged)
I send the gridview in the following event as a parameter to another method:Button1_click event.

```
protected void subjectdropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
         DataTable getmarkfdb = inter.getmarksfromdatabaseothers(comp);
         if (getmarkfdb.Rows.Count > 0)
         {
                TemplateField lable1 = new TemplateField();
                lable1.ShowHeader = true;
                lable1.HeaderText = "AdmissionNumber";
                lable1.ItemTemplate = new gridviewtemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "AdmissionNumber", "AdmissionNumber", "Label");
                studmarkgrid.Columns.Add(lable1);

                TemplateField label2 = new TemplateField();
                label2.ShowHeader = true;
                label2.HeaderText = "RollNumber";
                label2.ItemTemplate = new gridviewtemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "RollNumber", "RollNumber", "Label");
                studmarkgrid.Columns.Add(label2);

                TemplateField label3 = new TemplateField();
                label3.ShowHeader = true;
                label3.HeaderText = "Name";
                label3.ItemTemplate = new gridviewtemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "Name", "Name", "Label");
                studmarkgrid.Columns.Add(label3);

                TemplateField extmep = new TemplateField();
                extmep.ShowHeader = true;
                extmep.HeaderText = "ExternalMark";
                extmep.ItemTemplate = new gridviewtemplate(DataControlRowType.DataRow, "ExternalMark", "ExternalMark", "TextBox");

                studmarkgrid.Columns.Add(extmep);

                studmarkgrid.DataSource = getmarkfdb;
                studmarkgrid.DataBind();


       }
}
```

In the TextBoxTemplate column of the gridview  I fill the Mark for student and in the following event i send the gridview to insertstumark method for read data from gridview and save into database. but in the insertstumark method gridview rows data are null.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
            comp.ACADAMICYEAR = acyeardropdown.SelectedItem.Text;
            comp.MEDIUM = mediumdropdown.SelectedItem.Text;
            string clas = classdropdown.SelectedItem.Text;
            string[] cs = clas.Split('-');
            comp.CLASSNAME = cs[0].ToString();
            comp.SECTIONNAME =Convert.ToChar(cs[1].Trim().ToString());
            comp.EXAMNAMES = examnamedropdown.SelectedItem.Text;
            comp.SUBJECTID = subjectdropdown.SelectedValue.ToString();
          //  studmarkgrid.DataBind();
           // System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grid = studmarkgrid;
           // System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grid = ViewState["stdmarkgrid"] as System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView;
            DataTable studtable = null;
           // System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grid = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView)ViewState["stdmarkgrid"];
            bool studm = inter.inserstumark(comp,stumarkgrid);
  }
```

What is the problem. I tried to stored the gridview in viewstate. but in the following line it through the error. How to solve this problem?

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView grid = ViewState["stdmarkgrid"] as System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView;
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, if the data is bound to the GridView too late in the Page Lifecycle, the GridView is rendered, and the data forgotten, so at the next PostBack, you won't have access to the GridView's underlying data source.

That looks like what's happening here.  Just save the result of `getmarksfromdatabaseothers` to ViewState so you can access it again as necessary.

Comment: sorry. that value is modifying  after getmarkfromdatabaseothers bind to studmarkgrid(that means i edit the gridview  ExternalMark value  and then i call the Button1_click event. so if i save the getmarkfromothers value in viewstate, then it will give me the old data not edited data. that is my problem.